# laravel where condition with the % operator

Tags: laravel

today i'm trying to get modulus operator in where laravel clause but i can't get it work and after make some google researches and read the documentation i post this may be some one can help me to get a solution

```
Produit::has('caracteristique.image', '=', 2)
                //->where('(caracteristique.image.caracteristique_id)', '=', 2)
                ->has('caracteristique.stock')
                ->where('market_id', Auth()->user()->market->id)
                ->where(DB::raw('count(`produits`.`caracteristiques`.`images`.`caracteristique_id`)'), '%2', [2])
                ->get();
```

i hope to select all products that have a relation with caracteristique table and for each caracteristique i have to find 2 iamge that come from the images table
i make this also

```
->has('caracteristique.image', '=', 2)
```

but the problem is this code is not ensure for each caracteristique like i can get 1 product with 2 caracteristique and 3 image but i suppose to have 4 image hope you understand my problem and hope you will help me to find a solution. thank you

here we have the models

produit

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\{
    Market,
    Caracteristique,
};

class Produit extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nom', 'detail', 'rabais', 'statut','demande', 'market_id'];
public function caracteristique()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Caracteristique::class);
}

public function market()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Market::class);
}

}
```

caracteristique

```
 namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\{
    Produit,
    Stock,
    Image,
};
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Caracteristique extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'produit_id', 'couleur', 'prix', 'quantite', 'size', 'disponible', 
    ];

    public function produit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Produit::class);
    }

    public function stock()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Stock::class);
    }

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }
}
```

image

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\{
    User,
    Caracteristique,
};
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'caracteristique_id', 'user_id', 'nom'
    ];


    public function caracteristique()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Caracteristique::class);
    }

    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

    }

}
```

produit can have multiple caracterisque but for each caracteristique it must have 2 images how i can i write this query to avoid query caractristique with one or doesn't have any image please?
and it just say error sql at line one after the %2 condition.

Comment: What does that where clause tries to achieve, you are counting it and what then?

Comment: for this caracteristique i have 2 image 
it suppose to make sure for each caracteristique i get 2 images come from the images table
or for simple i want to make things like that som(caracteristique_id) % 2 == 0

Comment: this is the sql error
(SQL: select * from `produits` where exists (select * from `caracteristiques` where `produits`.`id` = `caracteristiques`.`produit_id` and (select count(*) from `images` where `caracteristiques`.`id` = `images`.`caracteristique_id`) = 2) and exists (select * from `caracteristiques` where `produits`.`id` = `caracteristiques`.`produit_id` and exists (select * from `stocks` where `caracteristiques`.`id` = `stocks`.`caracteristique_id`)) and `market_id` = 1 having SUM(`produits`.`caracteristiques`.`images`.`caracteristique_id`) % 2 = 0)

Comment: Can you post your models. If i see your relations then may be i or someone can help

Comment: and there is missing a part of that error, here it is just saying the raw sql

Comment: ok let me post the models